# mysql timestamp, where clause to filter today records in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, localhost

i have mysql table with timestamp field that records the datetime this way: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I simply want a query to limit all records of today,

```
SELECT (*) FROM mytable WHERE stampfield = CURDUTE()
```

I tried CURDATE() but didn't work!

I have another field date in the table and the CURDATE() works fine, but with this timestamp field it doesn't work!!

thanks in advanced

Comment: Because timestamp and date are not the same fieldtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timestamp fields include a time value, obviously. curdate() doesn't. Since you're doing `date+time v.s. date`, PHP will auto-extend your date value to have a 0 time, e.g.

```
curdate() = '2014-08-28'
timestamp = '2014-08-28 12:34:45'

timestamp = curdate() -> '2014-08-28 00:00:00' = '2014-08-28 12:34:45' - > false
```

try

```
date(timestampfield) = curdate();
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the date part from the timestamp, one way would be to use [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
SELECT (*) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE DATE(stampfield) = CURDATE()
```